# How can interact with process on dart?

Tags: dart

**How can put username and password on git command?**

I`m try this, but, only the stderr listener is called, with the output error described above and exit code 128

The output error:

*fatal: could not read Password for 'https://username@bitbucket.org': No such device or address*

```
void shell() async {
  var process = await Process.start('git', ["remote", "show", "origin",],
      workingDirectory: "directory/repot");
  process.stdout.transform(utf8.decoder).listen((event) {
    if(event.contains("Password")) {
      process.stdin.write("123456789");
    } else if(event.contains("Username")) {
      process.stdin.write("user.name");
    } else {
      print("output git command: " + event);
    }    
  });  
  process.stderr.transform(utf8.decoder).listen((event) {
    print("output erro: " + event);    
  });
  process.exitCode.then((event) {
    print("exitcode: " + event);  
  });
}
```

Comment: Define "dont work".

Comment: you have `if(event.contains("Password"))` and then `else if(event.contains("Password"))`

Comment: @chiliNUT this code do not execute.

Comment: @Abion47, I improved the error message.

Answer (score 2):

I think the code logic runs well try these steps to fix your problem:

1. Run the commands without the code with your terminal and get a full understanding of all commands and their errors.
2. Try another way to use a repository that's required passwords and usernames in bitbucket like this example in [question with answers](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/git-clone-without-password-prompt/qaq-p/1415240)
   or in Github
   git clone https://username:password@github.com/username/repository.git